# Is my Stan model correct? The Jeffreys prior for a heteroscedastic mixed-effects model

Tags: heteroscedasticity, prior, hierarchical-bayesian, stan, rstan

I am using rstan to obtain MCMC samples from a heteroscedastic mixed-effects model with different residual variances $\sigma_j^2$ for each experimental condition $j$.

One assumption is the Jeffreys prior for the grand mean and the residual variances,

$\pi(\mu,\sigma_1^2,\dotsb,\sigma_C^2)\varpropto\prod_{j=1}^{C}\sigma_j^{-2}$,

where $C$ is the number of conditions.

**Could you help me check if my rstan model file is correct** (perhaps not)**?** Thanks.
*Reference: https://osf.io/mrud9/*

```
data {
  int<lower=1> N;        // number of subjects
  int<lower=1> C;        // number of conditions
  vector[C] Y[N];        // responses
  real tcrit;            // critical value
  real<lower=0> ht;      // (square root of) scale parameter of the standardized treatment effects
  real<lower=0> hb;      // (square root of) scale parameter of the standardized subject-specific random effects
}

parameters {
  real mu;                           // grand mean
  vector<lower=0>[C] sigma_squared;  // error variances
  real<lower=0> gt;                  // variance of the standardized treatment effects
  real<lower=0> gb;                  // variance of the standardized subject-specific random effects
  vector[C] t;                       // treatment effects
  vector[N] b;                       // subject-specific random effects
}

transformed parameters {
  vector<lower=0>[C] sigma;  // error sd
  real<lower=0> va;          // average error variance
  vector<lower=0>[C] eta;    // sd of the treatment effects
  real<lower=0> tau;         // sd of the subject-specific random effects
  sigma = sqrt(sigma_squared);
  va = sum(sigma_squared) / C;
  eta = sigma * sqrt(gt);
  tau = sqrt(va * gb);
}

model {
  // linear mixed-effects model
  for (i in 1:N) {
    Y[i] ~ normal(mu + t + b[i], sigma);
  }
  t ~ normal(0, eta);
  b ~ normal(0, tau);

  // priors
  // mu ~ implicit uniform prior           // Jeffreys prior
  target += -2 * sum(log(sigma));          // Jeffreys prior
  gt ~ scaled_inv_chi_square(1, ht);
  gb ~ scaled_inv_chi_square(1, hb);       // Rouder et al. (2012)
}

// compute HDI boundaries based on Nathoo, Kilshaw, & Masson (2018) and Heck (2019)
generated quantities {
  vector<lower=0>[C] se;
  matrix[C,2] hdi_se;
  vector[C] mu_t;  // condition means

  se = sigma / sqrt(N);
  mu_t = mu + t;
  hdi_se[,1] = mu_t - tcrit * se;  // lower bound
  hdi_se[,2] = mu_t + tcrit * se;  // upper bound
}
```

So far, it is syntactically correct.

Edit: I have changed `target += -2 * (log(prod(sigma));` into `target += -2 * sum(log(sigma));` according to the comment below. However, I still wonder this `target +=` is correct or not.

Comment: I would certainly swap out `target += -2* log(prod(sigma));   // Jeffreys prior` for `target += -2* sum(log(sigma));   // Jeffreys prior` for improved numerical stability. Also - could you clarify where `tau_squared` comes into the model? Your prior density is independent of $\tau$

Comment: Thank you, jcken. When the homoscedasticity holds, my linear mixed model for the mean response would be $Y_{ij}=\mu+\sigma(t_i + b_j)+\epsilon_{ij}$, $\epsilon_{ij}\overset{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, for $i=1,\dotsb,C;\ j=1,\dotsb,N$. Here, $b_j$ is the subject-specific random effect, and $t_i$ is the treatment effect. Both have been standardized to the standard deviation of the error. Now, I want to study the heteroscedastic data. Basically, $\sigma$ is replaced by $\sigma_i$ and I am not sure if the random effect can still be written as $\sigma_i b_j$.

Comment: Continued. When the homoscedasticity holds, the priors are (1) $\pi(\mu,\sigma^2)\varpropto\frac{1}{\sigma^2}$; (2) $b_j\mid g_b\overset{\text{ind.}}{\sim}\mathcal{N}(0,g_b)$ and $t_i\mid g\overset{\text{ind.}}{\sim}\mathcal{N}(0,g)$; (3) $g\sim\text{Inv-}\chi^2(1,h^2)$ and $g_b\sim\text{Inv-}\chi^2(1,h_b^2)$; (4) $h=0.5$ by default. Now, I need to move onto the heteroscedastic data.

Comment: In case you wonder, $\mu$ is the grand mean. And $\mu_i=\mu+\sigma t_i$ in the homoscedastic linear mixed model.