# How do I write the Jeffreys prior for error variances in stan? $p(\mu, \sigma_1^2, \dots, \sigma_C^2) \propto \Pi{ \sigma_i^{-2}}$

Tags: heteroscedasticity, stan, heterogeneity, jeffreys-prior, rstan

I need to model the Jeffreys prior for error variances in a heteroscedastic ANOVA design in *rstan*.

That is to say, $\pi(\mu,\sigma_1^2,\dotsb,\sigma_C^2)\varpropto\Pi_{i=1}^{C}\sigma_i^{-2}$.

Is the following setting correct?

```
target += -2 * sum(log(sigma));
```

It seems not, because my current codes return an MCMC divergence warning.

Thank you for the kind comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of the Jeffreys prior for the standard deviation parameter [appears to be correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffreys_prior#Gaussian_distribution_with_standard_deviation_parameter). However, I suspect that you may not be bounding your  `sigma` parameters to be positive, and hence stan may often be initializing `sigma` to negative values, resulting in a MCMC divergence warning, since `log` is not defined for negative numbers.

For example, you can declare `real<lower=0> sigma` to specify it as a positive parameter.

```
data {
  int N;
  vector[N] y;
}
parameters {
  real mu;
  real<lower=0> sigma;
}
model {
  target += -2 * log(sigma);
  y ~ normal(mu, sigma);
}
```

Alternatively, the Jeffreys prior on $log(\sigma)$ is uniform, so if you reparameterize the model using `log(sigma)` as your parameter, then you can eliminate the `target += -2 * log(sigma);` statement, for example:

```
data {
  int N;
  vector[N] y;
}
parameters {
  real mu;
  real log_sigma;
}
transformed parameters {
  real sigma = exp(log_sigma);
}
model {
  y ~ normal(mu, sigma);
}
```

Comment: Initial values would not cause divergent transitions (which are a serious issue), but it could be that a sensible specification of the parameter bounds (or using log-sigma) could help with avoiding divergent transitions. Nevertheless, it's also possible that one has "correctly" specified a model and still gets divergent transitions. This is, by the way an improper prior, so that could cause issues, too. Of course, there's the option of simply increasing adapt_delta, e.g. `control=list(adapt_delta=0.99)` as an extra call to the statement where you sample.

Comment: You are absolutely right that using improper priors can result in an improper posterior, and hence may result in divergent transitions. In this case, I tested the model with a reasonable amount of input data, but without the positive bound on `sigma` using pystan, and got the following error message:
"WARNING:pystan:50 of 4000 iterations ended with a divergence (1.25 %)."
which is why i came to the conclusion that the missing bound might have lead to this question.

Comment: Thank you,b-r-oleary. I know how to initialize the parameters (but the warnings still exist). `vector<lower=0>[C] sigma;` Note $\sigma_i$ is a vector.

Comment: More details: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/531632/is-my-stan-model-correct-the-jeffreys-prior-for-a-heteroscedastic-mixed-effects